# How to check JAX-WS output from the URL

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws, soap-client, soapserver

I create a jax-ws service for get some data.I user **tomcat 8.5.11**.. The web service works fine and when I put the URL the WSDL shows and it previews all web methods... But it doesn't preview the output(XML) of each methods. How can I preview the output... I'm the service provider... **I want to know how the output will be preview to the clients**...

This is my web service class.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package lk.slsi.webService;

import java.util.List;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import lk.slsi.domain.CustomsPermit;
import lk.slsi.services.permitServices;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


@WebService(serviceName = "customsPermit")
public class webServiceforCustoms {

    @Autowired
    private permitServices permitServices;


    @WebMethod
    public List<CustomsPermit> getXmlbyDate(String dtIssue) {
        List<CustomsPermit> permitRelease = permitServices.getPermitByDate(dtIssue);
        return permitRelease;
    }

    @WebMethod
    public CustomsPermit getXmlbyEntryNo(String SNumber) {
        CustomsPermit permitRelease = permitServices.getPermitBySNumber(SNumber);
        return permitRelease;
    }

    @WebMethod
    public List<CustomsPermit> getXmlbyVATNo(String importerVAT) {
        List<CustomsPermit> permitRelease = permitServices.getPermitByImporterVAT(importerVAT);
        return permitRelease;
    }
}
```